# Django User Register, auto login & redirect

Tags: django, authentication, django-views

I collect two forms at signup - a register form and a user profile form.
The form submission works alright - I get to see the new user and their profile on the admin panel. The problem would be automatically logging them in and redirecting them to a specific page doesn't seem to work.

This is what my views.py file look like:

```
def registerView(request):

    regForm = RegisterForm
    proForm = UserProfileForm
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        regForm = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        proForm = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        


        if regForm.is_valid() and proForm.is_valid():
            user = regForm.save(commit=True)
            
            profile = proForm.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

            profile.save()

            
 
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

            if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return render (request, 'main/dashboard.html', {})
        else:
            return HttpResponse("There was a problem signing you up!")


    
        
    regDic = {'regForm': regForm, 'proForm': proForm}
    return render(request, 'person/register.html', context=regDic)
```

What would be the best way to automatically log in & redirect the registered user upon form submission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use the `cleaned_data` from the valid form instead of getting the raw values  and then instead of `render` the template `redirect` to some path after the successful login.

And also the `authenticate` function should have `request` as the first parameter.

```
 username = regForm.cleaned_data.get('username')
 password = regForm.cleaned_data.get('password')
 user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
 if user is not None:            
      login(request, user)
      return redirect('some_path')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using redirect instead of render.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
if user:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('name of the url you want to redirect')
```